# How to get the exact status code when checking connectivity between two servers in Linux using wget?

Tags: linux, bash, wget

We have new Linux DB servers. I am writing a script to check the connectivity from our servers to new DB servers. Based on the exit status code, I wrote my script to give an output if it is connected/connection refused or connection timed out.

All our servers dont have telnet, so I have to check with `wget`.

Ny sample code to capture the status:

```
m=`echo $?`
if [ $m -eq 124 ]; then
b="Connection Timed Out"
else
if [ $m -eq 6 ]; then
b="Connected"
else
if [ $m -eq 0 ]; then
b="Connected"
else

if [ $m -eq 4 ]; then
b="Connection Refused"
```

But for new Linux DB servers, we are getting a different status code as 258, even though it is showing as connected:

```
--2019-09-18 09:53:14--  http://xxx:80/
Resolving xxxxx... xxx
Connecting to xxxx|xxxx|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...  

echo $?
258
```

This is now misleading even though it has connectivity. Kindly suggest how we can get the exact status.

Comment: Are you sure you want to run a web server on your database servers? I would think  you'd to want to know if your *dbms* was listening on a particular port. What problem are you really trying to solve? Do you have any monitoring in place?

Comment: `awaiting response...` doesn’t look like connected to me. Did you kill the process? Anyway, it’s likely the least significant 8 bits of the exit code are what you’re interested in, the rest look like the result of a signal(?).

Comment: @Mike, I just gave the 80 port as reference, but I am trying to host my app server not the webserver

Comment: @Biffen, It says connected and next does the HTTP awaiting response, I had to manually kill the process

Comment: @SivaMalla That probably explains the >255 exit code. Surely you’re not expecting the script to do that?

Comment: @SivaMalla Are you using `wget` on a port that doesn’t serve HTTP?

Comment: @Biffen, yes, using wget for http port

Comment: Any help from anybody

Comment: I'd suggest using `nc` if you simply want to check a port is open

Comment: nc cannot be installed on these servers

Comment: Are you doing your own monitoring on DB servers? if yes, consider one of you DB client program.

Comment: Use 'nc'. See https://superuser.com/q/621870/155550

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTTP status codes for checks.

```sh
DB_STATUS_RESPONSE="$(wget --spider --server-response http://ipecho.net/plain 2>&1 | awk '/^  HTTP/{print $2}')"
if [ $DB_STATUS_RESPONSE -eq 200 ]; then b="Connected"; fi
```

```sh
$ echo $b
Connected
```